# When does Javascript function execute? php variables are not changing passed in arguments

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-app-engine

I have a javascript function that takes parameters from php

the javascript function is executed after the page is loaded

I set initial settings on my php variables

set up my javascript functions

do some php magic, reassign my php variables

and when my javascript function loads - its using my initial values instead of what they are last assigned at.

```
$lat = 0;
$lon = 0;
  <script>
var map;
function initialize(lat,lon) {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { initialize(<?php echo $lat ?>,<?php echo $lon ?>); });

    </script>


$lat = $newvallat;
$lon = $newval;
```

the function is called with the arguments 0,0

can I call the addDomListener later?

Comment: Of course, that part of the page is rendered with the value PHP had for `$lat` and `$lon` in the instant it created the snippet. What did you want to accomplish?

Comment: What did you expect? `$s=0; echo $s; $s=10;` would you expect 10? Yes you can call `addDomListener` later, or preferably execute all your php business logic before you output anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a client-side language. PHP is a server-side language. You cannot use Javascript to pass arguments to PHP within the same script in a single run. For what you're trying to do, you want to AJAX call a PHP file with what the Javascript DOMListener is being fired on.

To answer your question, Javascript is "run" the instant it's loaded by the browser, whereas PHP is parsed when it's being read by the server (which is consequently, **before** the browser gets and parses the output).

Comment: True, but not relevant to this question - his problem is more straight forward, in that he outputs the javascript before he has set the correct values for his php variables

Comment: this makes sense - I switched it to give me the lat/lon on previous page and now have the values I need before the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Echo puts the current value of the variable into the response.  Changing that variable  will have no effect on the JavaScript as it is getting what was echoed.

The JavaScript runs after the page is presented to the browser, with whatever values were built on the server.

You could use Ajax to get the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going through Google tutorials? https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

In the link I provided it will show you how to save the marker to an XML document first then do with it as you please. There are more links provided there if you need more instructions. I find Google maps has very good documentation and tutorials even.